# gstreamer: display various image on top of video

Tags: gstreamer

I wrote a video player based on gstreamer. Now I need to display status images on top of playing video when some event is occurred. I tried following pipeline for testing purposes

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! autovideosink filesrc location=pic.jpg ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! imagefreeze !  mix.
```

to display image (implemented in C). To hide image I set pipeline to `GST_STATE_READY`,  unlink and remove `location`, `jpegdec`, `videoconvert` and `imagefreeze`  and set pipeline back to playing state but that doesn't work (video is not playing anymore).

Could someone suggest the right way of showing and hiding images on top of playing video?

Comment: Did you try not only unlinking but also removing the elements from your pipeline? Also did you dumped dot files of your pipeline? They can tell you a lot of useful information

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also removing elements after unlinking.